# Create an entry per item in an iterable of unknown length with Tkinter

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

---

### SEE UPDATE AT END OF POST!

Okay lets see if i can explain this correctly.  I am coding a script using Tkinter that essentially will set up a configuration file for a larger code package.  One of the Toplevel popups is going to be for Editing of an already existing record.  What I'm trying to do is create a Toplevel widget that will include several static items plus the key/value pairs in a dictionary and I'm wondering if its possible to create a widget where the number of entry boxes depends on the length of the dictionary.

For example if i have a dict containing this:

```
accounts={'abcd@gmail.com':{'pass':'password','type':'Gmail','disabled':False}}
```

I would want an Entry Widget for the Email, password, type, and disabled setting and with this one:

```
accounts={'abcd@gmail.com':{'pass':'password','type':'Gmail','disabled':False, 'retries':'3'}}
```

has the same as the one above plus the retries option that I could retrieve with a button click i.e.:

```
b=Button(top, text='Save Changes', command=getvariables)
```

---

### -----------------------------UPDATE-------------------------------

@atlassologist you're solution got me on the right track.  I tinkered with it until it was giving me the output I was looking for

[here](https://github.com/Amazingred/ABRAhaM/blob/master/pkgs/ABRAhaM_CONFIGUI.py) is the full configui.py code on github

Here is the shortversion of the code that finally worked:

```
from Tkinter import *

accountsdict={'abcde@gmail.com':{'disabled':'True', 'type':'live','password':'pword'}}

class EditAccounts:
    def __init__(self, parent, account):
        self.value_list=[]
        top=self.top=Toplevel(parent)
        Label(top, text="Editing Account information").grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky='ew')
        row=1
        for k,v in accountsdict[account].iteritems():
            var=StringVar()
            var.set(v)
            Label(self.top, text=k).grid(row=row, column=0)
            Entry(self.top, textvariable=var).grid(row=row, column=1)
            row+=1
            self.value_list.append((k,var))
        Button(self.top, text="Cancel", command=lambda: self.top.destroy()).grid(column=1, row=20)
        Button(self.top, text="Save", command=self.save_changes).grid(column=0, row=20)

    def save_changes(self):
        for i in self.value_list:
            print i[0], i[1].get()

class SelectAccountToEdit:
    def __init__(self):
        root=self.root=Tk()
        Label(root, text="Select an account to edit").grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)
        self.accounts=Listbox(root)
        for k in accountsdict.keys():
            self.accounts.insert(END, k)
        self.accounts.grid(column=0, row=1, rowspan=3, columnspan=2)
        self.ok=Button(root, text="Select", command=self.select)
        self.done=Button(root, text="Done", command=self.root.destroy)
        self.ok.grid(column=0,row=4,sticky='ew')
        self.done.grid(column=1,row=4,sticky='ew')
        self.accounts.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2,rowspan=3, sticky='ew')
        mainloop()

    def select(self):
        acnt=self.accounts.get(self.accounts.curselection())
        d=EditAccounts(self.root, acnt)
        self.root.wait_window(d.top)

SelectAccountToEdit()
```

Comment: Yes, it's all possible. What have you tried? Can you show us what research you've already done to solve this?

Comment: I'm going to post a copy on pb in a bit and i'll update the link.  Each mainwindow button opens a toplevel widget (each widget has its own class) so for the two options where I need this operation I've tried creating a function inside the class that creates a new entry/label and then I basically iterated through dict.iteritems() and for each one of those, ran the function.  Had limited success but I haven't been able to .get() the entries for each variable if/when the user changes them so that I can save them back in the config file.  I'll post a bit more on the code in a sec

Comment: Try posting the smallest working version of the program in your question rather than on pastebin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplified example of some of the functionality that you want. Hopefully it gets you set off on the right foot. I'd also recommend looking at the docs for [iterating over dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) and the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#usage) module, which is excellent for saving and accessing dictionaries without any hassle.

```
def save_changes():
    for i in value_list: # access the list of stringvars
        print i.get()    # and print the .get() method of each

root = Tk()

d = {'item1':'value1', 'item2':'value2'}
value_list = []

row=1
for k,v in d.iteritems(): # iterate over k,v in dict
    var = StringVar()
    var.set(v) # set var to value of dict item
    Label(root, text=k).grid(row=row, column=0)
    Entry(root, textvariable=var).grid(row=row, column=1)
    row+=1
    value_list.append(var) # append the stringvar instance to a list

Button(root, text='Save', command=save_changes).grid()

mainloop()
```

Note: There are other ways to do this, probably better ways, even, and you will most likely need to make a lot of adjustments for it to work with your data and specifications. This is just a starting point.

Comment: Okay This looks interesting.  the row+=1 and row=row with saving the StringVars in a list isn't something I have tried yet.  I'm going to try to use that and see if that does what I'm looking for.

Comment: This got me thinking exactly how i needed to be.  See the OP for the update and the code that worked.  Thank you